# Is the PECL imagick extension also vulnerable to the new ImageMagick security issue?

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick, pecl

I'm asking, if the [PECL imagick extension](https://pecl.php.net/package/imagick) is also vulnerable to the  new very critical ImageMagick security issue (check [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=29588) and [here](http://www.openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2016/05/03/18)). Is the extension just using the ImageMagick tool via shell, too?

Comment: Reading the security section of the readme for Imagick is usually a good idea as well... https://github.com/mkoppanen/imagick#security

Comment: @Danack: Thanks, I agree. I didn't notice that the Imagick extension is on Github.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes.

The Imagick PECL is a PHP binding to the [C-API MagickWand](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick-wand.php). It does not invoke a shell session, but is vulnerable to the delegate security issues -- just the same.

## Update the `policy.xml` as recommended by the notice.

*edit for completion*

How to updated `policy.xml` (YMMV)

- Locate ImageMagick's shared path on system.

  ```
  $ identify -list configure | grep SHARE
  #=> SHARE_PATH    /usr/share/ImageMagick-6
  ```
- Create or edit `policy.xml` in directory of previous step.

  ```
  $ cd /usr/share/ImageMagick-6
  $ sudo cat > policy.xml <<EOF
  <policymap>
   <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="EPHEMERAL" />
   <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="HTTPS" />
   <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="MVG" />
   <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="MSL" />
   <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="TEXT" />
   <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="SHOW" />
   <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="WIN" />
   <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PLT" />
  </policymap>
  EOF
  ```
- Verify policy loads with `identify -list policy`.
- Restart web-services to ensure new policies are loaded.